# Add one Java program as a dependency in another program using Maven.

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

There are many related questions to this but I am getting confused with the answers from them and decided to ask this myself. I have a Java program and want to use it in another one. How can I add the first one as a dependency in the POM.xml file of the second program?  The IDE I am using is IntelliJ version 13.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Java program"?  In general, you declare dependencies on artifacts, typically Jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is pom.xml of project A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>a</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

After you compile project A through `mvn install` command, you can add project A into project B by using `<dependency>` of project A

suppose this is pom.xml of project B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytest2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>b</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.a</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

See more information : [How do I add a project as a dependency of another project?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html)

Comment: The 'mvn install' part is what I missed. All I did was package it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If the first java program was built with maven (it has pom.xml with groupId:artifactId:version), you can add it as a dependency into your new project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>old-program-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>old-program-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>version-you-want-to-re-use</version>
</dependency>
```

If no - it would be very complicated way (in size of an article)...

Comment: @AswinJoseRoy You do not need to add any jar file of first project into another project, you just add dependency into another project. See my post.

Comment: no. I guess you build old application on the same machine. so it is already in the local maven repository (~/.m2/repository/...). IDEA will automatically resolve this dependency and required jar files.

Comment: @ursa, thanks. But, this is the case because I'm running my program in local. What should I do when I want to run the program in a remote system? Like a cluster deployment.

Comment: to run or to build? if to run, then you need to read about applications packaging with maven assembly plugin. if to build - you need to deploy you old application into repo (you company internal or sonatype).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make one a dependency of the other would be to put them together under a parent POM. Building multi-module Maven project is easy. [This](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) will get your started. Once you have created the parent pom and referenced it in the two modules, just use a standard maven `<dependency/>` tag in the one needing the dependency and create a new Intellij project that imports from the parent POM.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps

- Create **jar** file (java archive) with your project.
- Execute

  *mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\your file.jar -DgroupId=your.id 
  -DartifactId=your name a -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar*

  to include at your local repository
- Add dependency to pom.xml

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>your.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  ```

Comment: do you ever see a java application within a single jar? in your approach maven will generate an empty pom.xml without dependencies.